# React Native: How to fade in when swiping carousel?

Tags: animation, react-native

I'm trying to implement a carousel (currently using React Native Swiper: https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper)

One thing I need is to fade the next slide in when the user is swiping:

[image]

Is there a way to do this? I don't mind doing it in react native without packages, I don't know what to look up or where to start though.

Comment: I would take a look at the animated library - http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html